# Is it possible to chain multiple methods to a delegate in one assignment statement?

Tags: c#, delegates, chaining

I want to chain together two (and possibly more in the future) methods to a delegate and just wondered if there is a way to do this in one assignment statement, e.g.

I have a delegate method signature defined as

```
public delegate void MaskRequestSection(Request request);
```

...and 2 methods that use this signature, namely...

```
public void MaskCvnSection(Request request)
{
    // do the masking operation
}

public void MaskCardNumberSection(Request request)
{
    // do the masking operation
}
```

At present, I am using the following to instantiate the delegete, chain the 2 methods to it and then invoke them...

```
private void HideDetailsInRequest(Request request)
{
    MaskRequestSection maskRequestSection = MaskCvnSection;
    maskRequestSection += MaskCardNumberSection;
    maskRequestSection(request);
}
```

....I am just curious as to why I can't chain both delegates in one statement like below,

```
MaskRequestSection maskRequestSection = MaskCardNumberSection+ MaskCvnSection;
```

...but also if there is another way that it can be done within one declaration. I haven't been able to find anything that specifically addresses this on MSDN, and I'm just asking for my own curiosity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175(v=vs.100).aspx) that addresses this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with a cast:

```
var maskRequestSection = (MaskRequestSection) MaskCardNumberSection
       + (MaskRequestSection) MaskCvnSection;
```

... but you can't do it without one, because the `+` operator here works on delegates, not method groups. When the compiler sees the binary `+` operator, it has to work out the type of the expression, and *that* doesn't take the assignment part into account.

Comment: Thanks for that Jon - after reading Eren's comment to my original question and your response, I see the difference. Cheers.